# How do we merge questions?

Tags: support

We've just closed [Class for Curriculum Vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/895) as a duplicate of [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80).  The text says "This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers **may be merged with another identical question**."  (emphasis mine).

How, exactly, do we do that merge?  In this case, there's no point in leaving both lying around and a couple of the answers on the closed question don't appear on the still open one so merging seems a good plan.

Comment: Maybe one needs access to moderation tools? They are currently at 2000 rep.

Comment: @Caramdir: In that case, everyone should go and find some questions of Joseph's to vote up.  He just needs two more days hitting the rep boundary to get to 2000!

Comment: @Caramdir: the relevant merge tool is strictly “official” moderators only – it can’t be accessed with any amount of reputation. At least that’s the situation on Stack Overflow. It may of course be different on other sites.

Comment: In that case: when do we get moderators?

Comment: @Caramdir: from the StackExchange blog: "That’s why I am in the process of identifying and organizing a team of provisional Moderators from within each community  (about three per site, **starting  about seven days into the public Beta**)."  So by this time next week, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7270/merge-question-after-finding-it-as-a-duplicate-feature-request) Meta.Stackoverflow question and answer.

They say it is a moderator only tool, but I don't know whether this would be slightly different here as we are still in beta.